# RCpp : how to reload recompiled C++ code without restarting R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm experimenting with the rcpp_hello_world example generated by `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`.

I made a small change to `rcpp_hello_world.cpp`, I would like to recompile the package and run the function with the modified code.

However, in spite of clearing the namespace with `rm()`, detaching the library with `detach()`, removing the package with r`emove.packages()`, re-compiling and re-installing the package with `install.packages(.., repos=NULL, type = 'source')`, and reattaching the library with `library()`, R still runs the old version of the .cpp code.

If I quit and restart R, `library()` will load the modified .cpp code and run it as intended, but I don't want to have to restart R everytime I make a change to the C++ code (if possible).

How can I get R to properly refresh the C++ call without quitting R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally advisable to restart the session / reload the package.

As you may not want to restart your main session, you can

- use Rscript or littler to load the new example and tests, I often do that
- use RStudio where the package build process now builds the package and reloads it in a fresh session for you
- use a system where you can have several R sessions and restart those

Comment: Or use devtools which also recompiles and reloads for you.

Comment: @hadley: But doesn't restart the session, does it?  I never found unloading / detaching to work reliably.

Comment: It works pretty well in my experience. Restarting is always the most reliable, but I haven't had any problems in my packages which use a few c functions.

Comment: I still can't seem to figure out how to use unload() to do the trick on OSX R 2.15.1. R still runs the older version of the function. Can you give an example? I tried this: library(mypackage), unload(inst('mypackage')), install.packages("mypackage", repos = NULL, type = "source", clean = TRUE, INSTALL_opts = '--no-multiarch'), library(mypackage), then reran the function.

Comment: Don't trust @hadley who doesn't do C++, trust JJ and me and rely on restarts. It is more reliable...

Comment: Any recommendations for speeding up the C++/R development workflow? Do you typically develop C++ code independently and port it over to R as a last step? It's not ideal to have "restart R" as part of an edit-compile-run cycle.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel have you looked at or tried the code in devtools? That was a rather rude dismissal of my work.